# How to calculate between days?

Tags: go, time, days

i'm new in golang. Can u teach me how to calculate between two days. This is my code, i want to calculate betweet Time and Created At

```
type ActivityHistoryData struct {
    AgentId            uint
    ActionName         string
    Time               time.Time
    ActorId            uint32
    AcqFullname        string
    CreatedAt          time.Time
}
```

Thank you

I' tried it, and there is some error in my code. Especially when i added time with created at. The error is "type ActicvityHistoryData has no method Time" and "type ActicvityHistoryData has no method CreatedAt"

Comment: Use a third party library like https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rickb777/date/period

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere in your code, in the part that you have not shared, you are adding `()` after the `.Time` and `.CreatedAt` fields. The expression `x.f()` (where `x` is not a package) represents a [method call](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls) and assumes `f` is a method of `x`. `Time` and `CreatedAt` are not **methods** of `ActivityHistoryData`, they are **fields** and therefore you SHOULD NOT append `()` to them.

To calculate the number of days between two `time.Time` values you can do the following:

```golang
var t1 time.Time = ...
var t2 time.Time = ...

numberOfDays := t2.Sub(t1).Hours() / 24
```

https://go.dev/play/p/GDI8VUiYsZn

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to calculate difference between two times.

Here is an example:
https://go.dev/play/p/h-dX4MqRf6p
keep in maind that, The Go Playground's `time.Now()` allways returns 2009-11-10 23:00:00